# How can I modify the SCSS in the existing project? There are no SCSS file in original

Tags: sass, build, version-control, reverse-engineering

I have to modify the project that someone made. The source seen through the Chrome browser does not exist in real. How could I update the project?

output.js is on the root directory and there is no code... nothing.

[image: my directory]
[image: these scss files are only in chrome]

Comment: Is their project on GitHub (or other VCS)? If so, it may be easier to just clone that to get the source code

Comment: I only know how to handle HTML, scss, and jQuery, but I got these source files from the manager's google drive. Asking me to modify the css and javascript. I usually use vcode. sorry,  there are no Github or VCS

Comment: You can see the original `scss` because there is a source map telling you where the code is originated from. But if you don't have access to the source files, you can still change the computed file, the `css` file. The only problem is that if someone who has access to the source file make a modification and push it to production, your changes will be erased.

Comment: She or he seems to have used 'webpack'. And he must have used 'source map' and 'inline' as an option. How can I restore these files back to their original state?